# Javascript RegEx to find string in url between slash and either comma or question mark

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to have javascript return value of 'sct' or 'rain' (strip the ",20" or ",70") from urls like:

```
<script>
var urls = [
"https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/day/sct,20?size=medium",
"https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/day/sct?size=medium",
"https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/night/rain?size=medium",
"https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/day/rain,60/rain,70?size=medium"
];
for(var key in urls) {
  console.log(get_icon(urls[key]));
}
function get_icon(text) {
 /* not sure what to do here */
}
</script>
```

The logic would be get string after last slash and before comma or question mark. I'm struggling with the regex statement to do that.

Comment: something like `\/(\w+)[^\/]*$` should do what you want; it looks for a group of alphanumeric characters following a slash with no slashes after it all the way to the end of the string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex with a greedy match of `.*` to make sure last `/` is matched:

```
/.*\/([^,?]+)/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/n8irS5/1)

`([^,?]+)` gives you string before next `?` or `,` in a capturing group.

**Code:**

```js
var urls = [
"https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/day/sct,20?size=medium",
"https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/day/sct?size=medium",
"https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/night/rain?size=medium",
"https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/day/rain,60/rain,70?size=medium"
];
for(var key in urls) {
  console.log(get_icon(urls[key]));
}
function get_icon(text) {
  return (text.match(/.*\/([^,?]+)/) || [null][null])[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this regex. Extract group 1 :

```
\S+\/(\w+,\d+|\w+)\?\w+=\w+
```

Answer (score 0):

Reply on your need, I can do:

```
function get_icon(text) {
   var pos = text.lastIndexOf("/");
   var qmark = text.lastIndexOf("?size");
   var res = text.substring(pos+1, qmark);
   var res = res.split(",");
   if (res.length == 2)
      return res[1];
   else
      return null;
}
```